# RevTeX 4.1 - How to change default \email footnote symbol from lettering to an asterisks

Tags: revtex, author, email

Publication requires an email footnote on the title page for the corresponding author denoted by an asterisk. Using `\email` below the corresponding author's name successfully creates the required footnote, but uses a) as default rather than an asterisk. Is there any way to change the symbol type used by `\email`, or is it better to create the footnote some other way?

Example code:

```
\documentclass[aip,jap,reprint,graphicx]{revtex4-1}

\author{author} 

\email[]{email@email.com}

\date{\today}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you tell us which document class you are using?

Comment: Document class is revtex4-1

Comment: The e-mail symbol seems to be `a)` for the AIP substyles of revtex4. If you are sure that the email should be put as an asterisk, check if `aip` is the correct option - if you remove it, an asterisk will be printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substyle file for `aip` does

```
\let\@fnsymbol@latex\@fnsymbol
\let\@fnsymbol\@alph
```

so all you need is to revert the redefinition, but also to flip a switch that would otherwise make the code for `\maketitle` to choose again `\@alph`.

```
\documentclass[aip,jap,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\makeatletter
\let\@fnsymbol\@fnsymbol@latex
\@booleanfalse\altaffilletter@sw
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{author}
\email[]{email@email.com}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Side note: there is no `graphicx` option to the document class. If you plan to include graphic files, add

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

instead.

Comment: This explanation nearly has it. Is there anyway to suppress the bracket so that there is only an asterisk?

Comment: Dear egreg, maybe you know the answer to this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/627699/41144 ? thanks so much!