# How to change the email footnote symbols to math symbols in the APS revtex?

Tags: math-mode, footnotes, document-classes, revtex, email

> How to change the email footnote symbol shown below "*" to some other math symbols, such as the symbol with subscript "b$_1$", "b$_2$", "c$_3$", "a$_4$"? (for paper with four authors, "b$_1$" for the first author, and so on.)

```
\documentclass[ap, notitlepage, superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}

 
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}


\author{1st Author b$_1$}
\email{abc@gmail.com}

\author{2nd Author b$_2$}
\email{b2@gmail.com}

\author{3rd Author c$_3$}
\email{c3@gmail.com}

\author{4th Author a$_4$}
\email{a4@gmail.com}

\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

This is a false example. I hope to change * to b$_1$, and so on others to b$_2$, c$_3$, and a$_4$.

**Question:**
How to change the Email symbol with definite symbols, that we can **specify by hand**:

- the 1st Author with Email symbol b$_1$,
- the 2nd Author with Email symbol b$_2$,
- the 3rd Author with Email symbol c$_3$,
- the 4th Author with Email symbol a$_4$.
  and so on that, we can specify each by hand.

[image]

Comment: this post maybe related but this seems not working for me for \documentclass[aps] ---- https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394590/41144

Comment: Using the code in the answer (not the answer but rather, the code that changes to alph) I was able to change the symbol to a or A. But I do not know how to add math into it. Maybe you could gobble the symbol altogether and Add it in the email string definition?

Comment: Unrelated: note that `revtex4-1` has been marked _obsolete_ and `revtex4-2` is now the recommended version

Comment: @Elad Den, can you post your partial answer? thanks so much!

Comment: @wonderich It's unclear how the footnote marks should be chosen.

Comment: Thanks, see update/clarify --- symbol with subscript "b$_1$", "b$_2$", "c$_3$", "a$_4$"? (for paper with four authors, "b$_1$" for the first author, and so on.)

Comment: Adding the following would change the footnote marks to arabic numerals, replace `arabic` with `alph` or `Alph` or `roman` to get something else.... `\makeatletter
\let\@fnsymbol@latex\@fnsymbol
\let\@fnsymbol\@arabic
\makeatother`

Comment: @wonderich So you are saying you want to name the author $b_1$ and that the symbol would be the name of the author? So if I name the author "Author McAuthorFace" I get `Author McAuthorFace AMAF@somedomain.com` in the mail footnote?

Comment: I just want to change the 1st Author with Email symbol b$_1$, 2nd Author with Email symbol b$_2$ and so on. See my update! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. (Using `revtex4-2`}

[image: c]

[image: d]

Nine user-defined footnote marks were created for the email. (easily expanded). If any of the new ones are not used, the default mark will be used.

```
\documentclass[aps, notitlepage, superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fmarki}{*}
\newcommand{\fmarkii}{\ensuremath{\dagger}}
\newcommand{\fmarkiii}{\ensuremath{\ddagger}}
\newcommand{\fmarkiv}{\ensuremath{\mathsection}}
\newcommand{\fmarkv}{\ensuremath{\mathparagraph}}
\newcommand{\fmarkvi}{\ensuremath{\|}}
\newcommand{\fmarkvii}{**}
\newcommand{\fmarkviii}{\ensuremath{\dagger\dagger}}
\newcommand{\fmarkix}{\ensuremath{\ddagger\ddagger}}
                
\def\@fnsymbol#1{{\ifcase#1\or \fmarki\or \fmarkii\or \fmarkiii\or \fmarkiv\or \fmarkv\or \fmarkvi\or \fmarkvii\or \fmarkviii\or \fmarkix \else\@ctrerr\fi}}
\makeatother

%% ************************************  define new email marks
\renewcommand{\fmarki}{b$_1$}
\renewcommand{\fmarkii}{b$_2$}
\renewcommand{\fmarkiii}{c$_3$}
\renewcommand{\fmarkiv}{a$_4$}
\renewcommand{\fmarkv}{x$_5$}
% <<<<<<<<<<<<<< ..... use default for 6, 7 and 8
\renewcommand{\fmarkix}{z$_9$}
%% ************************************

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{titlepage}
        
        
        \author{1st Author}
        \email{abc@gmail.com}
        
        \author{2nd Author}
        \email{def@gmail.com}
        
        \author{3rd Author}
        \email{ghi@gmail.com}
        
        \author{4th Author}
        \email{a4@gmail.com}
        
        \author{5th Author}
        \email{x5@gmail.com}
        
        \author{6st Author}
        \email{w6@gmail.com}
        
        \author{7nd Author}
        \email{x7@gmail.com}
        
        \author{8rd Author}
        \email{y8@gmail.com}
        
        \author{9th Author}
        \email{z9@gmail.com}    

        
        \maketitle
    \end{titlepage}
    
\end{document}
```

See the [alternatives-to-asterisk-and-star-for-superscripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146923/161015) nice answer.

Comment: Thanks, +1 this is nice. I am confused why do we need to restart with \newcommand{\fmarki}{*}? if we are going to \renewcommand{\fmarki}{b$_1$} ? Could you explain why this paragraph after 
\makeatletter is important?

Comment: @wonderich To have a default behavior in case a mark is not defined. See the cases of 6, 7 and 8.

Comment: Yes I got your point.